in high charts vu bar not getting proper pane , always coming to 0 , i need to come to 1
i want dial should show value 1 but its showing 0 , how to change the pane value. how to show the dial with value 1 . after changing the data point also its not changing in the vu dial. minimum value is 0 and max value is 1 and i want to show the needle at 1 , but the needle showing 0 always.


high charts Code

Highcharts.chart('vu-meter-pressure', {
    chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBackgroundImage: null,
        height: 200
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Oil Level'
    },

    pane: [{
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        background: null,
        center: ['50%', '60%'],
        size: '110%'
    }],

    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },

    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },

    yAxis: [{
        min: 0,
        max: 1,
        minorTickPosition: 'outside',
        tickPosition: 'outside',
        labels: {
            rotation: 'auto',
            distance: 20
        },
        plotBands: [{
            from: 0.5,
            to: 1,
            color: '#C02316',
            innerRadius: '100%',
            outerRadius: '105%'
        }],
        pane: 0,
        title: {
            text: '<span style="font-size:8px"></span>',
            y: -40
        }
    }],

    plotOptions: {
        gauge: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            dial: {
                radius: '100%'
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: '',
        data: [1],
        yAxis: 0
    }]

});


The provided code works correctly on my side, could you please add more details about when does this issue occur and if there are any errors logged to the browser console? In a demo below, you can see that it seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qs9byz12/
